# routing is ignored by symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony application (version 1.4). I want to see index page of main module in frontend app when I only type `projectname/` but it ignores and shows symfony default project successfully created page. My `routing.yml` in `C:\wamp\www\tr\apps\frontend\config\routing.yml` is:

```
homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: main, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

I couldn't find the mistake. Please help.

Comment: I don't see a problem in the info you are providing, maybe something else is going on. Do you have other applications besides frontend? Or maybe there is more to your routing.yml than you are pasting. Not directly related but I would suggest removing the 2 default routes at the bottom. It's best practice to replace them with unambiguous routes.

Comment: what do have in the main/index action? the skeleton is created with a redirect to default/index. make sure you have removed this line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your cache.

Symfony caches all config files in the production environment - it means if you change anything in them, you need to clear your cache (or at least delete the cached version of the given config file, so it doesn't need to re-cache everything).

By using your app via the index.php front controller, you're using the prod environment.

For development purposes it's recommended to use the appname_dev.php front controller, where such caching barely exists (it automatically reloads every config file, excluding i18n translations).

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
homepage:
  url:   /:module:action
  param: { module: main, action: index }
```